# Laravel 8 Nexmo sending to international numbers with nexmo.sms_from dynamic config

Tags: php, laravel, vonage

I'm using version 2.5.1 of the nexmo-notification-channel which I see is now known as the vonage-notification-channel. I'm based in the UK and have customers globally, I have set my sms_from to be the following:

```
'nexmo' => [
    'sms_from' => 'DomainMonit',
]
```

A change happened on 1st March 2022 beyond my control whereby sending to US numbers now requires the use of a toll-free number as described here.

Currently, my sms_from works perfectly fine for sending to UK based numbers, but, I'm going to need to buy a toll-free number, and somehow configure the sms_from to use the toll-free number for specific US customers (I have a column in my database I can utilise to get country), how can I change the sms_from dynamically to support this?

All SMS sent to the US must originate from either a US pre-approved long number, registered toll-free, 10 DLC, or short code that is associated with your Vonage account. Alpha Sender IDs are not supported.

I'm using: `laravel/nexmo-notification-channel` 2.5.1

Answer (score 0):

Just for clarification - can you let me know if you are actually using the nexmo-notification-channel or the vonage-notification-channel?

Because the difference is quite important in that they use different versions of the underlying Core Vonage library.

Apologies for the answer- I can't use comment because of rep.

Comment: I'm using `laravel/nexmo-notification-channel` @Jim

Comment: OK so this feels more like a Laravel question than a Vonage one. I'll have a look into the easiest way to make a dynamic config, but it's going to involve your controller, job or event handling the config container.